# How can I test a custom mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, mailgun

I am trying to test the functionality of a follow up email through rails that I want to be sent after a user emails a url bookmark address to mailgun (which I've tested and is working).  I am not sure if my code for the mailer is set up correctly or not, but there is no follow up email being sent when I send an email to mailgun.

Here is my custom mailer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content= 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Hi <%= @user.name %>,</h1>
        <p>
          This is just a friendly email to let you know the following bookmark was saved:
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= @bookmark.url %>
        </p>
      <p>
        Cheers! <br/>
        Bookmarks.com
      </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is my incoming controller code:

```
class IncomingController < ApplicationController
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  def create
    Rails.logger.info "INCOMING PARAMS HERE: #{params}"
    Rails.logger.info "Topics: #{params[:subject]}"
    Rails.logger.info "Url: #{params['stripped-text']}"
    Rails.logger.info "User email: #{params[:sender]}"
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:sender])
    Rails.logger.info "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ User: #{user.inspect}"
    if user
      @bookmark = Bookmark.new(url: params['stripped-text'])
      topics = []
      topic_names = params[:subject].split(' ')
      topic_names.each do |topic_name|
        name = topic_name.sub(/#/, '')
        topics << Topic.find_or_create_by_name(name)
      end
      if @bookmark.save
        topics.each do |topic| 
          @bookmark.topics << topic
        end
        user.bookmarks << @bookmark
        FollowUpMailer.notify(@bookmark).deliver
      end
    end    
    head 200 
  end
end
```

And here is my create url bookmark code:

```
def create
    @bookmark = Bookmark.new(bookmark_params)
    @bookmark.user = current_user
    if @bookmark.save
      topic_names = params[:topic_names]
      topic_names = topic_names.split(' ')
      topic_names.each do |topic_name|
        name = topic_name.sub(/#/, '')
        topics << Topic.find_or_create_by_name(name)
      end
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @bookmark, notice: 'Bookmark was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @bookmark }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @bookmark.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end   
  end
```

The only way I have been testing this is by sending an email through mailgun via production and looking at my local rails server logs (which show no signs of action), and so I can't figure out how else to test the mailer locally in development, as I am still new to programming.  Could I get some ideas for how to test to get some errors to work with?  Thanks!

Question Edit:
I forgot to add my follow_up_mailer.rb code:

```
class FollowUpMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "valeriemettler@gmail.com"

  def notify(bookmark)
    @bookmark = bookmark

    mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Your bookmark was saved!')
  end
end
```

This is the error I get after testing with FollowUpMailer.notify(Bookmark.first).deliver:

```
2.0.0-p481 :001 > FollowUpMailer.notify(Bookmark.first)deliver
SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks to me like the error is that you're not initializing an `@user` variable in your Mailer method, though you reference that in the view. I think defining that variable will fix that (one) error. The general testing tips below still apply, though. You can test the mailer directly in the console (locally) without hitting that Controller at all.

Comment: Valerie -- that's just a typo (syntax error == typo). `deliver` is a method, and so needs a `.` before it: `FollowUpMailer.notify(Bookmark.first).deliver`

Comment: @Sasha--thanks for catching the typo!  When I initialize the instance variable user in the Mailer method and then test it in the console, it comes back the same with or without initializing the user variable:  NameError: uninitialized constant FollowUpMailer.  Any thoughts? :)

Comment: Was your rails console open for a long time? You might just have to close and reopen it. That seems the most likely, unless you're in the production console or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Quick note, before the rest of the answer. Your local server SHOULD show nothing when you're sending/receiving messages on Production. You should look in your production server logs (`heroku logs`) to see what's working/erroring. However, I don't think that's the best way to test this, so my full answer below...

A mailer needs several parts in Rails. You've got most of them, but you appear to be missing the Mailer Class -- ie `FollowUpMailer`.

That file should be in `app/mailers/follow_up_mailer.rb`, and it should define a `notify` method which is what is called when you run that line of code in your controller.

Check out the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) on the subject for what that method should look like, how you pass variables to the view, and what the view should be named, and where it's located.

More generally, I'd suggest trying to move some of this logic into the Bookmark model. This may not seem relevant, but it will make your life much easier. If you dissociate the mailing behavior from the controller, you can more easily test mailing directly.

Maybe create a `save_and_notify` method on the Bookmark class, and throw an error in the controller if it doesn't return true. That method would encompass the last few lines of your action:

```
    topics.each do |topic| 
      @bookmark.topics << topic
    end
    user.bookmarks << @bookmark
    FollowUpMailer.notify(@bookmark).deliver
```

And it would also have to take `topics` and `user` as arguments.

There are a number of ways to move some of this logic into the model. That's just one. Once you've done that, you can more easily test bookmark saving and message sending from your Rails Console, or write tests for it as well.

> Note that you could also test mailing directly in the console right now already. Just do this: `FollowUpMailer.notify(Bookmark.first).deliver`. Any errors encountered sending that should be raised in the console. Be sure to set up a message interceptor though, otherwise, you'll send live messages whenever you test this.

---

To fix one error in your mailer, you need to define an `@user` variable in your `notify` method. That variable is used in the mailer view but not defined in its associated method (basically the controller action for a mailer). Alternately, you could extrapolate the user from the bookmark in the view `@bookmark.user.name`. Either way, try testing this out in the local console, and you'll get immediate feedback about whether or not it's working.

Comment: Thanks, @Sasha!  I forgot to add my follow_up_mailer.rb in my question.  Does that change your advice in any way?  I will also add the error I got when I ran FollowUpMailer.notify(Bookmark.first).deliver as you suggested.